# How to show keyboard on phone in alert Dialog?

Tags: android, keyboard, android-alertdialog

I can't find a way to ge the keyboard from my phone to pop up when I show an alert dialog where users can input an amount of players in an editText. Because of that I can't type anything in the editText when I run the app on my physical phone. Here is also the code for my Main and dialog class:

Main:

```
package com.example.joppe.firstapp;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements 
spelersDialog.spelersDialogListener {
    private TextView textView_test;
    private Button button;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        textView_test = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView_test);
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                openDialog();
            }
        });
    }

    public void openDialog() {
        spelersDialog SpelersDialog = new spelersDialog();
        SpelersDialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "spelers Dialog");
    }

    @Override
    public void applytexts(String number) {
        textView_test.setText(number);
    }
}
```

alertDialog:

```
package com.example.joppe.firstapp;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDialogFragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class spelersDialog extends AppCompatDialogFragment {
    private EditText players;
    private spelersDialogListener listener;

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_dialog, null);

    builder.setView(view)
            .setTitle("Number of players:")
            .setNegativeButton("cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                }
            })
            .setPositiveButton("apply", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    String number = players.getText().toString();
                    listener.applytexts(number);
                }
            });
    players = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.players);

    return builder.create();
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);

    try {
        listener = (spelersDialogListener) context;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
       throw new ClassCastException(context.toString() +
       "must implement spelersDialogListener");
    }
}

public interface spelersDialogListener {
    void applytexts(String number);

}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in dialog fragment

```
 @Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    //Show the keyboard
    players.post(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            players.requestFocus();
            InputMethodManager imm =
                    (InputMethodManager)etMeterValue.getContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            if (imm != null)
                imm.showSoftInput(etMeterValue, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: What is the 'etMeterValue' supposed to be? It stays in red.

Comment: Please checked I have edited the answer. It is the edit text view in which you have to open the dialog. In your case it is players.